# microsite landing page not opening exacttarget

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have created a simple html page in content-->microsite and i have auto published it. When i try to open it from URL generated i am getting error as

**The page you have requested is unavailable!**

Can anyone tell do i have to change some settings to make it work. Below is the screenshot of the error that i am getting -

[image]

Regards

Comment: Have you created the Microsite in Interactions and started it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Adam said in his comment, you need to create a Microsite Interaction. 
The 'microsite interaction' is basically the switch to turn on or off your site. Auto-Publish will just keep the most up to date version showing on the site, not actually make it available online.

You need to go to the interactions tab in Marketing cloud and go to the 'Microsite Interactions".  There you must create an interaction linking your microsite/landing page to it. After creation you then have to turn it on and then go back to your page and it should load.

ref: http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/microsites/